# Best practice for logging .net core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Learning How to build web applications with net core. what is the best way to log events and errors?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NLog, ASP.NET Core provides some logging providers, such as Console, Debug, while they cannot log to a file. By using NLog, you can save the app log to a file or even a database. Steps are:

First, install NLog NuGet package:

```
Install-Package NLog.Web.AspNetCore
```

Then create a config file named `nlog.config` in the project used by NLog like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     autoReload="true">
  <variable name="logDir" value="${basedir}/logs" />
  <targets>
    <target name="logFile" 
            xsi:type="File" 
            fileName="${logDir}/log_${shortdate}.log" 
            layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"/>
    <target name="logConsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logConsole" final="true"     />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

For more detail info about the above config file, you could read this: [NLog Configuration file](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file)

In `Configure` method of `Startup` class, add the following code to add NLog logging provider and its services

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    …
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Finnally, you can use NLog in your controllers:

```
public ValueController(ILogger<ValueController> logger)
{ 
    Logger = logger;
}

public ILogger<AuthorController> Logger { get; }
```

As to log exception, you can create a class implementing `IExceptionFilter`, which is a MVC filter in ASP.NET Core and can capture exceptions while app is running, you can also inject the NLog logger in the filter.

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter:IExceptionFilter
{
    public GlobalExceptionFilter(IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        Environment = env;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // log exception and show its details
        }
        else
        {
            // log exception and show generic error info
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you can apply that filter in `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {    
        config.Filters.Add<GlobalExceptionFilter>();
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```